# Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am trying to conduct a cluster analysis, which requires me to scale/standardise my data. The data is in a matrix and is numeric, however I am only getting the following message:

```
Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric
```

Initially, there was a column containing categorical data, so I removed that, thinking this would solve the problem, but I still received the error.

Following is the chunks of script and 6 rows of data. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

```
Metals <- as.matrix(d)
rownames(Metals)<-d$RowLabs
cols_to_keep <-c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE) 
Metals<-Metals[,cols_to_keep]
head(Metals)
```

```
    X88Sr_umol_molCa X25Mg_umol_molCa X55Mn_umol_molCa X7Li_umol_molCa
CHR1 "1748.3722"      "    80.284613"  " 1.353754e-01"  "   3.2146056" 
CLR2 "1763.6984"      "   104.850260"  " 4.944963e-01"  "   0.2649073" 
CLR3 "2245.8861"      "   186.579911"  " 2.124642e-01"  "   1.0715352" 
CLR4 "1654.9811"      "   124.502777"  " 4.756491e-01"  "   0.2252010" 
CLR5 "1447.3079"      "   183.703436"  " 4.734605e-01"  "   2.8409970" 
CLR6 "1731.3718"      "   170.511088"  " 1.728970e-01"  "   2.5984728" 
     X138Ba_umol_molCa
CHR1 " 1.3426978"     
CLR2 "10.3955650"     
CLR3 "12.8552971"     
CLR4 "12.3339241"     
CLR5 " 0.9453284"     
CLR6 " 2.1714244"
```

```
d <- scale(Metals)
head(Metals)
```

Error in colMeans(x, na.rm = TRUE) : 'x' must be numeric

Comment: Hey Angela! From the 6 lines of data that you provide, it looks like your numbers are being interpreted as characters by R (because they are between quotation marks - ""). Perhaps that is why the error is appearing. You can transform these numbers, by applying the as.double() function.

Comment: Besides that. Next time you ask help, please, use dput() function on your "d" object, to provide a proper way to reproduce your data. The 6 lines of data that you provide, does not help us very much to solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your help Pedro. I'm not sure why they are in quotation marks. How do I remove them?

Comment: I just edit the past comment. You can use the as.double() function on your "d" object, that problably works.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the dput() function also. How exactly would this look? Can you please show me with the code I provided?

Comment: Do you mean as.double() instead of the dput() function ?

Comment: Could you please show me how this should look I'm a little confused

Comment: The dput() function will print the R code necessary to recreate your "d" object. So you copy and paste on your StackOverflow question, this code that results from dput() function. With this code, we can reproduce your "d" object. Now, the as.double() function, is just to transform the data that is inside "d" object to numeric values.

Comment: Is this what you meant?                                        ```{r}
Metals <- as.matrix(d)
rownames(Metals)<-d$RowLabs
cols_to_keep <-c(FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE) 
Metals<-Metals[,cols_to_keep]
head(Metals)
```

Comment: ```{r}
Metals1<-as.double(Metals)
head(Metals1)
d <- scale(Metals1)
head(d)
dput(d)
```

Comment: Angela, just try to apply the colMeans() function after you transformed your d object: colMeans(as.double(d), na.rm = TRUE)

Answer (score 1):

The table is wrongly read in, you can see that for example under the column "X25Mg_umol_molCa", your entries are strings and have a leading space, for example,  "    80.284613".

Most likely there are some entries in your file that's causing it to be read like this, and not as a numeric column. I think the first you should try to do is use for example:

```
df = read.table(<file>,header=TRUE,sep="\t")
str(df)
```

And see whether the columns are now numeric.

With your current few rows, we can do something to remove the whitespace, hopefully it solves the problem:

```
df = structure(c("1748.3722", "1763.6984", "2245.8861", "1654.9811", 
"1447.3079", "1731.3718", "    80.284613", "    104.85026", "   186.579911", 
"   124.502777", "   183.703436", "   170.511088", " 1.353754e-01", 
" 4.944963e-01", " 2.124642e-01", " 4.756491e-01", " 4.734605e-01", 
" 1.728970e-01", "   3.2146056", "   0.2649073", "   1.0715352", 
"   0.2252010", "   2.8409970", "   2.5984728", " 1.3426978", 
"10.3955650", "12.8552971", "12.3339241", " 0.9453284", " 2.1714244"
), .Dim = 6:5, .Dimnames = list(NULL, c("X88Sr_umol_molCa", "X25Mg_umol_molCa", 
"X55Mn_umol_molCa", "X7Li_umol_molCa", "X138Ba_umol_molCa")))

 df
     X88Sr_umol_molCa X25Mg_umol_molCa X55Mn_umol_molCa X7Li_umol_molCa
[1,] "1748.3722"      "    80.284613"  " 1.353754e-01"  "   3.2146056" 
[2,] "1763.6984"      "    104.85026"  " 4.944963e-01"  "   0.2649073" 
[3,] "2245.8861"      "   186.579911"  " 2.124642e-01"  "   1.0715352" 
[4,] "1654.9811"      "   124.502777"  " 4.756491e-01"  "   0.2252010" 
[5,] "1447.3079"      "   183.703436"  " 4.734605e-01"  "   2.8409970" 
[6,] "1731.3718"      "   170.511088"  " 1.728970e-01"  "   2.5984728" 
     X138Ba_umol_molCa
[1,] " 1.3426978"     
[2,] "10.3955650"     
[3,] "12.8552971"     
[4,] "12.3339241"     
[5,] " 0.9453284"     
[6,] " 2.1714244"

df = apply(gsub(" ","",df),2,as.numeric)
scale(df)

     X88Sr_umol_molCa X25Mg_umol_molCa X55Mn_umol_molCa X7Li_umol_molCa
[1,]     -0.064262779       -1.3718203       -1.1268227       1.1249317
[2,]     -0.005975399       -0.8234489        0.9806457      -1.0696716
[3,]      1.827842350        1.0009771       -0.6744341      -0.4695329
[4,]     -0.419440351       -0.3847518        0.8700426      -1.0992135
[5,]     -1.209246479        0.9367664        0.8571990       0.8469633
[6,]     -0.128917342        0.6422776       -0.9066306       0.6665231
     X138Ba_umol_molCa
[1,]        -0.9263654
[2,]         0.6466464
[3,]         1.0740455
[4,]         0.9834525
[5,]        -0.9954117
[6,]        -0.7823672
attr(,"scaled:center")
 X88Sr_umol_molCa  X25Mg_umol_molCa  X55Mn_umol_molCa   X7Li_umol_molCa 
     1765.2695833       141.7386808         0.3273904         1.7026198 
X138Ba_umol_molCa 
        6.6740395 
attr(,"scaled:scale")
 X88Sr_umol_molCa  X25Mg_umol_molCa  X55Mn_umol_molCa   X7Li_umol_molCa 
      262.9419965        44.7974607         0.1704039         1.3440690 
X138Ba_umol_molCa 
        5.7551172
```

Answer (score 0):

Your data seem to be characters. What does `class(Metals)` return?

Turn the data to numeric and then try the `scale` function :

```
Metals[] <- as.numeric(Metals)
d <- scale(Metals)
```

Answer (score -1):

Matrix's on R, are vectors with 2 dimensions, so by applying directly the function as.double(), you should be able to transform your data that is inside your matrix, to numeric values.

```
d <- as.double(d)
```

See if that works.

Comment: class(Metals) returned:   [1] "matrix" "array"

Comment: This change to the original script solved the problem: Metals <- as.matrix(d[,-1])
rownames(Metals)<-d$RowLabs
head(Metals)